# Preventing Column Looping in (R)handsontable

Tags: javascript, r, handsontable, rhandsontable

I'm currently working with Rhandsontable and I'm facing an issue with user cell selection. When a user selects a cell from the last column (say column C) and then presses the right keyboard arrow, the selection loops back to the first column (column A). I would like to prevent this behavior and make it similar to Excel, where you cannot go further once you reach the final column.

Here's a simple example of my current Rhandsontable

```
library(rhandsontable)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
rhandsontable(df)
```

In this example, if a user selects a cell from column C and presses the right arrow key, the selection jumps back to column A. I want to prevent this looping behavior.

---

**Edit**

Based on Stéphane answers, I generalized his code to all the arrow keys and also included an exception for the SHIFT and CTRL key combination. Although the SHIFT combination is working as default, the CTRL one is not working.

library(rhandsontable)
library(htmlwidgets) # to use the onRender function

```
js <- c(
  "function(el, x) {",
    "var hot = this.hot;",
    "const firstCol = 0;",
    "const lastCol = hot.countCols() - 1;",
    "const firstRow = 0;",
    "const lastRow = hot.countRows() - 1;",
    "Handsontable.hooks.add('beforeKeyDown', function(e) {",
      "if(e.which == 37 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) { // Left key",
        "e.stopImmediatePropagation();",
        "e.preventDefault();",
        "const selected = hot.getSelected();",
        "if(selected !== void 0) {",
          "const [row, column, row2, column2] = selected[0];",
          "if(column != firstCol) {",
            "hot.selectCell(row, column - 1);",
          "}",
        "}",
      "}",
      "if(e.which == 38 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) { // Up key",
        "e.stopImmediatePropagation();",
        "e.preventDefault();",
        "const selected = hot.getSelected();",
        "if(selected !== void 0) {",
          "const [row, column, row2, column2] = selected[0];",
          "if(row != firstRow) {",
            "hot.selectCell(row - 1, column);",
          "}",
        "}",
      "}",
      "if(e.which == 39 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) { // Right key",
        "e.stopImmediatePropagation();",
        "e.preventDefault();",
        "const selected = hot.getSelected();",
        "if(selected !== void 0) {",
          "const [row, column, row2, column2] = selected[0];",
          "if(column != lastCol) {",
            "hot.selectCell(row, column + 1);",
          "}",
        "}",
      "}",
      "if(e.which == 40 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey) { // Down key",
        "e.stopImmediatePropagation();",
        "e.preventDefault();",
        "const selected = hot.getSelected();",
        "if(selected !== void 0) {",
          "const [row, column, row2, column2] = selected[0];",
          "if(row != lastRow) {",
            "hot.selectCell(row + 1, column);",
          "}",
        "}",
      "}",
    "});",
  "}"
)

df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
rhandsontable(df) %>% onRender(js)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do for the right arrow.

```r
library(rhandsontable)
library(htmlwidgets) # to use the onRender function

js <- c(
  "function(el, x) {",
  "  var hot = this.hot;",
  "  const lastcol = hot.countCols() - 1;", # the index of the last column
  "  Handsontable.hooks.add('beforeKeyDown', function(e) {",
  "    if(e.which == 39) {", # 39 is the key code for the right arrow
  "      e.stopImmediatePropagation();",
  "      e.preventDefault();",
  "      const selected = hot.getSelected();",
  "      if(selected !== void 0) {",
  "        const [row, column, row2, column2] = selected[0];",
  "        if(column != lastcol) {",
  "          hot.selectCell(row, column+1);",
  "        }",
  "      }",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "}"
)

df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
rhandsontable(df) %>% onRender(js)
```

With newer versions of the **handsontable** library, we could use the following JavaScript code instead:

```r
js <- c(
  "function(el, x) {",
  "  var hot = this.hot;",
  "  const lastcol = hot.countCols() - 1;",
  "  const gridContext = hot.getShortcutManager().getContext('grid');",
  "  gridContext.removeShortcutsByKeys(['ArrowRight']);",
  "  gridContext.addShortcut({",
  "    group: 'navigation',",
  "    keys: [[ArrowRight]],",
  "    runOnlyIf: () => hot.getSelected() !== void 0,",
  "    callback: () => {",
  "      const selected = hot.getSelected();",
  "      const [row, column, row2, column2] = selected[0];",
  "      if(column != lastcol) {",
  "        hot.selectCell(row, column+1);",
  "      }",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "}"
)
```

But **rhandsontable** is not maintained and uses an old version of **handsontable**.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I wonder if there's a way to generalize your approach to all arrows (top, bottom, left, right), so that the selection remains "boxed". A pitty that rhandsontable does not rely on the latest handsontable version.

Comment: @mat I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean to keep to arrow cell navigation "boxed". Here you prevent moving from the last column to the first one. I'd like to prevent as well the opposite, from the first to the last. Moreover, I also want to prevent passing from the last row to the first and vice versa. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @mat Of course this is possible, you just have to do three additional `if(e.which == x)`, where `x` is the key code of the arrow key. But I don't understand why you say "boxed".

Comment: Thanks!! Also, I just noticed that your code breaks the SHIFT + Right arrow selection behavior, is there a way to fix that? Same with CTRL + Right arrow selection method.

Comment: @mat Isn't it `e.which == 37 && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey` instead? Maybe you wanted to do, equivalently, `e.which == 37 && !(e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey)`.

Comment: I updated my edit following your suggestions, but for some reason when using CTRL the selection is able to go through the edges. I think that, by default, you are not able to go through the edge with SHIFT but you can do this with CTRL

Comment: @mat If you want to handle the selection when an arrow key is pressed as well as the CTRL key, you have to define its behaviour in a `if(e.which == 37 && e.ctrlKey)`. Here you have the default behavior.